Wedge product and iterated integral
Let's work on the real plane in polar coordinates $(\rho, \theta)$ and let $f(\rho,\theta)$ be a function of class $C^2$. My problem is the integration of the fowwing 2-form on the  disc $B(0,r)=\{v\in\mathbb R^2\colon ||v||<r\}$:
$$
\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{d\rho}{\rho}\wedge df
$$

In particular I cannot understand the following equality: $$
 \int_{B(0,r)}\frac{d\rho}{\rho}\wedge
df=\int^r_0\frac{d\rho}{\rho}\int^{2\pi}_0df $$

As far as I know  when we are integrating a 2-form on the plane we can remove the wedge and pass to the "nested integration" only when we  are able write something like $g(\rho,\theta)d\rho\wedge d\theta$.
It is true that in my case written above the first term $\frac{d\rho}{\rho}$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, bit still I cannot formally explain the iterated integration.

The equality is indeed sloppily written. Who is to know what $\int_0^{2\pi} df$ means?

The full equality is $$\int_B \frac{1}{\rho} \ d\rho \wedge df = \int_B \frac{1}{\rho} \ d\rho \wedge (\partial_\rho f d\rho + \partial_\theta f d\theta)=\int_B \frac{1}{\rho} \ d\rho \wedge  \partial_\theta f d\theta$$
